# Postman newman handle status codes

Tags: postman, newman

I have a question if it is possible to have more than one status code check in test.
Case is 201 when user is created and 409 when user already exist when i re-run test cases with same batch of users. 201 is handled but 409 not. a

```
 var data = pm.response.json()
 pm.test("Status test", function () {
  return  pm.response.to.have.status(200) || pm.response.to.have.status(409);
     
});


There was an error in evaluating the test script:  JSONError: Unexpected token 'U' at 1:1 User already Exists ^
```

EDIT:

For `200` i am getting user object i cannot post this object here

for `409` string User already Exists

Comment: Could you please show the response bodies for both cases?

Comment: please take a look edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant way to test for status 200 or 409 would be:

`pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([200, 409]);`

The error occurs when status is 409, because then the request doesn't return JSON, but a string.
I would put something like

```
if (pm.response.code == 200) {
    var data = pm.response.json()
    // your code
}
```

But I strongly advise you, not to do this!
In terms of testing, you want one test to only check for one thing. Otherwise this most probably will lead to misunderstandings and increased maintenance effort.

I would propose to create one request to create users, with according tests. And another one, that tries to recreate the users, again with according tests.

Comment: i add your code pm.test("Status test", function () {
 pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([200, 409]);
     
}); but still failed i am getting this as a test rsult when 409 is returned There was an error in evaluating the test script:  JSONError: Unexpected token 'U' at 1:1 User already Exists ^

Comment: When the status is 409, the request doesn't return JSON, because of that, the `var data = pm.response.json()` in the first line is failing. This is why I added the `if (code == 200) {...}`, to only try to parse the response as JSON, when the status is ok and JSON has been returned.